# CSS: Using an svg as a background url variable?

Tags: css, svg, css-selectors

I have had an issue using an SVG as a background image for a CSS var

folder stucture:

```
components
 -index.ts 
 -styles.css
icons
 -handle-icon.svg
```

inside my styles.css, I have:

```css
:host {
  --corner-svg: url(../icons/handle-icon.svg);
}

.cont {
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: var(--corner-svg);
}
```

However, in my browser, it doesn't load up the SVG and I see `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` in the console.

Comment: Try using `:root` instead of `:host`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a string value as a parameter to the `url` function, since you are using a relative path.

Replace:

```css
--corner-svg: url(../icons/handle-icon.svg);
```

with:

```css
--corner-svg: url("../icons/handle-icon.svg");
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.